Is it possible to detect entanglement by observing only one of the entangled particles?
For example, suppose an entangled electron and anti-electron have been produced in an inertial center-of-mass frame. If we have just a single detector and it observes a positron, then it's probably from such a pair. But does anything about the positron other than its rarity suggest that it is entangled, if we do not also observe the other particle of the pair?

This question is very similar to: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/827320/another-entanglement-question-can-you-tell-if-the-wave-function-of-an-entangle And as WillO says, the answer is "NO".

Let V and W be the state spaces of the individual particles.  An observable G acting on V acts on $V\otimes W$ by acting on the first factor, and it's easy to check that the eigenspaces are all of the form $H\otimes W$ where $H$ is an eigenspace of G acting on V.  So nothing in the outcome of a measurement of G can reveal the entanglement.
